# 14.04 - Laptop Battery Indicator does not show the right battery percentage

Tags: 14.04, unity, power-management, indicator, battery

Despite my battery is full; the battery indicator shows it as `'98%'`. When I click on it it says `"Battery(charged)"`. Is this a bug? And how can I resolve this issue?

***psi. My laptop is new & I do not have any issues with MS Windows.***

Comment: Did my answer help you? Could you please either give me a comment on my answer or accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that it is a bug. The Linux kernel will not charge the device when it is almost full to preserve the battery. It will only start charging again when it is below 90 % or so. It will only go to 100 % when it is charging from less than say 90 %.